# Parsing Data from Text File from a Flash Chromatography System

Tags: python, parsing

I am a beginner coder and I have been tasked with parsing code from a flash chromatography system in my lab group. My overall goal is to separate the data that is used to make a graph for chromatography analysis. The data that I need is between  and . All the other data is unnecessary. Within this data, I would need to parse the data into the time (denoted by x), Wavelength1 (denoted by w1), Wavelength2 (denoted by w2) and WavelengthAll (denoted by wa). I am struggling to write a code that would find the data within the  and  and parse it in the way I would like it to. I have attached a couple of photos of the raw data that comes from the system and would appreciate any help I can get! Thanks!

[RawData1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIlVS.png)
[RawData2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9VmM.png)

Comment: Your files are in XML format.  Python has a very good XML module with a couple of different mechanisms.  You should read about it.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)